# most of apt not working. (caused by wine packages)

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dpkg, dependencies

Hey I have a problem I know what is causing it. But somehow I can get packagemanagement to work along.

```
> joeri@laptop-K55VD:~$ sudo apt-get remove wine
wine32-development  wine-development    winetricks
wine64-development  wine-rt-amd64       
wineasio-amd64      wine-rt-i386        
joeri@laptop-K55VD:~$ sudo apt-get remove wine-rt-amd64 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-rt-i386:i386 : Depends: wine-rt:any (= 2:2.0.1-1~kxstudio1)
                     Recommends: libgif4:i386 but it is not installable
 wineasio-amd64 : Depends: wine-rt-amd64 but it is not going to be installed or
                           wine-staging-amd64 but it is not installable or
                           wine-amd64
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This one of the many things I tried. I simply figured out to get rid off wine as a whole.

The output of apt --fix-broken install is this:

```
> joeri@laptop-K55VD:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-16 linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-16-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-16-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  wine-rt
Suggested packages:
  dosbox:any winbind
Recommended packages:
  ttf-droid | fonts-droid
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  wine-rt
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1195 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6268 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 461604 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../wine-rt_2%3a2.0.1-1~kxstudio1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wine-rt (2:2.0.1-1~kxstudio1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/wine-rt_2%3a2.0.1-1~kxstudio1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/wine/fonts/ssef1256.fon', which is also in package fonts-wine 2.0.2-2ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wine-rt_2%3a2.0.1-1~kxstudio1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Not usefull either I would love to use my package manager again. Please help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this

But I spended a few good hours (about 4 with other methods)

get synpatic from here: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/17.10/ubuntu-universe-amd64/synaptic_0.84.2_amd64.deb.html

download it with the dependencies.

cd ~/Downloads

sudo dpkg -i synaptic(version).deb
and same goes for the dependencies.

Use the broken filter within synaptic. And just remove all of it in my case.

Comment: The official Ubuntu package archive is https://packages.ubuntu.com/ I'm not sure about pkgs.org or how often it's updated. Anyway, maybe just removing the broken packages one at a time with `apt` / `apt-get` would have worked

Comment: It has been updated within even the beta version of the next Ubuntu release. but yes the packages.ubuntu.com would also be nice for this. Also in my case the issue is that apt refused to remove the broken packages as well.

Comment: Synaptic is just a frontend for apt, so apt eventually did remove them somehow. Maybe Synaptic did it in a special order or one at a time, or knew which one to remove first somehow. I definitely prefer synaptic though, and aptitude is supposed to be very good too (it's a gui-like terminal application).

Comment: Tbh, the fact that I do cybersecurity research I kinda should have looked at what it was doing which is possible though. And yeah I know what it is. I just stopped using it when it didn't come with Ubuntu as standard. to me it should though. But honestly, this solution works most of the time for people who run into compareable problems.